# If \$var is not \!

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script which currently produces a result like this:

```
...
Processing !
Processing $6$vxVOJhOX$U2flG.WASP1fEsqNy1Q0S9YROgdNJi9TTC8Gn74Al4w03unxr4qtHeaeRl8sWsGLG4Om5WbUJVsqNaCD4t4tG.
Processing !
Processing $6$ehmLTmoj$VP72RBNibmjwngQxMrW0kiyax/wJHiV0ugv/8J2RJnCwNxTIBLGJ.A4t5ryZv6lQTyheoA6N0VianZC5QI7Rp1
Processing !
Processing !
...
```

I want to filter out entries with just `!`.

I'm trying the following, both with and without escaping on the `\!`:

```
while read -r line ; do
  if ! [ \$line = \! ]; then
    echo "Processing $line"
  fi
done
```

How do I check if a variable contains a single `!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your sample output has more text on the line ("Processing"), and
2. You escaped the dollar sign in `\$line`, preventing variable expansion.

Try:

```
while read -r line; do 
  if ! [ "$line" = "Processing !" ]; then 
    echo processing line "$line"; 
  fi
done
```

Or, if your input is being *provided* by the sample script, then just compare `$line` to `\!`:

```
while read -r line; do 
  if ! [ "$line" = \! ]; then 
    echo processing line "$line"; 
  fi
done
```

or perhaps more directly:

```
while read -r line; do 
  if [ "$line" != \! ]; then 
    echo processing line "$line"; 
  fi
done
```